# Best way to test disaster recovery in a virtual environment

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, disaster-recovery

We are using vCenter, eSXi 5.1 and Acronis vmProtect to run and backup a network of virtual machines, both windows and *nix based. it is the latter I am interested in today.

Some of these still run homebrewed, file-level backup scripts, which I would like to turn off and reclaim the disk usage from. First though, I would like to test the recovery of the vmProtect backups.

We have a second host - far less specced than our main one - which I can use for testing. I understand that I can deploy a vm to it which is not connected to the vSwitch of the main host.

I am looking at how we could then test the functionality of the deployed vm - that is, we would need to ensure that the vm still serves pages fine (in the case of a webserver), that SSL is working, that the database is in sync with the filesystem etc etc. As far as I can see, the only way to do this would be to also deploy a windows vm to the separate vSwitch, so the two can see each other without affecting the production network.

Is there an easier way? Is there a way to deploy the VM and have it accessible at it's normal IP from my physical workstation, but not the other workstations on the network?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another NIC to your desktop (I use USB dongles for this) and build a separate test network on that NIC using a 4- or 8-port hub.

Or, for less desktop configuration hassle, build the isolated network and physically change your desktop's network cable from reality that network.

Either way, the hassle with an alternate network is the need to recreate services taken for granted, DHCP, etc.